# Can't install Python 3 / Jupyter on Catalina properly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to install python 3 and jupyter on Catalina.
I installed the latest version (3.7) from Anaconda distribution, but if I type
`python --version` in the command line I get "Python 2.7.16"
If I type `jupyter notebook`, i get `zsh: command not found: jupyter`
I have also installed python 3.8.2 from python.org, I thought this might help.
What can I do now to get it running?

Comment: You need to modify your zsh profile `nano ~/.zshrc` and update it with the respective PATHs for Jupyter (should be in your current `.bash_profile`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use python3 --version to see if you have python3 installed or not

suggest use brew install python to install python3
https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python

Comment: ok this works, 'python3 --version' gives me the right version. But how do I get jupyter running?

Comment: which version python3 does it return? the one u installed from Anaconda or python.org?

Comment: it returns 3.7.4 from anaconda

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1493257/cannot-open-jupyter-notebook-in-the-new-zsh-shell-in-macos

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for the jupyter problem:

1. cd into your installation directory of anaconda in terminal
2. Go into bin folder and drag the binary named conda into the terminal and type init zsh